# Advanced height 100% without using positon absolute

Tags: html, css, height

Let's say that I have a page with a main div which height is assigned automatically depending on the content that is inside of it. Now let's say that inside of this main div I have a fixed-width sidebar (for example: 250px) with position: absolute. Now I want to make a block which height is 100% and width 100% - 250px of the right sidebar. I can't use position: absolute because there's no possibility to use margin-right: 250px (nor padding-right: 250px; on the main div).

Also I can't use height: 100% on the main block because as I said - its height must depends on the content.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using JS ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand — why is using a left padding out of the question? You should demonstrate your issue with a Fiddle.

Comment: because position: absolute will make it ignore the padding attribute.

Comment: No, not when you use it on the content block. Again, Fiddle, or else we can't help. Based on my interpretation of your question, using a left padding is not a problem at all: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/zYKxn/

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HYWqB/2/ . Now #subject must be always height: 100% (I am in a need to make it fluid). Now when I add some absolute positioning here, nothing works properly.

Comment: You should look into this article - http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: Now I've got this: http://jsfiddle.net/4bspR/3/ . How can I make the left column's width the same - the right column?

Comment: Ops sorry. I mean that #someBlock inside of it